# How to keep the ImageView inside the bounds of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an imageview left aligned with a textview. The width attribute of the textview has value "wrap_content". The problem is whenever the length of the text inside the textview is exceeds a limit the image view goes out of the visible screen. How to set a limit to the width of textview so the imageview remains inside the bounds of screen?

[image]

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/question_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_dp"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/united_logo"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorBlack"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/user_dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_dp"
            android:text="A small text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_name"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/posted_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_info"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="5th July, 10:23 IST"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Let us see your xml

Comment: here it is. @mTak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a drawable image at the end of the textview, drop the ImageView and use this for your TextView:

```
        android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.